# Sonarqube url redirection using apache

Tags: apache, sonarqube, redirect

I would like to redirect the old overview dashboard to the new. To do this I configured an apache server but the Redirect doesn't work and I don't know why. Here is the configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
DocumentRoot D:/wamp64/www
<Directory  "D:/wamp64/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>

ProxyPass / http://localhost:9000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9000/

Redirect /overview /dashboard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/overview$ /project/extension/dashboardPlugin/sbi-overview [L,R=301]
```

These lines will move from /overview to the other page usine [Rewrite Rules](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/fr/mod/mod_rewrite.html)